# CSS3 rotate on youtube player doesn't work on IE FF

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, css, youtube, rotation

I want to rotate a youtube player, 
here my code => 
http://jsbin.com/abihux/11/watch

I used css3

```
-moz-transform:    rotate(15deg);
-o-transform:      rotate(15deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
transform:         rotate(15deg);
```

It works well on chrome, but not on ie9/ ff18 (windows).

On FF I have a black screen, on IE, youtube players is not rotated

I also tried with YouTube Embedded Players (same problems) 
and unfortunatly we can't force HTML5 player...

Someone has a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct vendor-specific property for IE would be `-ms-transform`.

In Firefox 17.0.1 and 18.0 (Windows 7 Professional), the link worked and the video was rotated.

Comment: Well I can confirm it does **not** work in Firefox 23.0.1 (Windows 7) - The rotated Youtube video displays as black, without any visible player control buttons